# Error about "Recycler View. No adapter attached, skipping layout"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have some problem about adapter, there is my `loadData()` method :

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String URL_DATA = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Malang&appid=2c869002c83226532f2ac719d5c80c49";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<List> listItem;
```

LoadData()

```
private void loadData (){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this) ;
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
                        JSONArray array = jobj.getJSONArray("weather");

                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            List item = new List(
                                    obj.getString("description"),
                                    obj.getString("main"),
                                    obj.getString("base")
                            );
                            listItem.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItem);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  }
}
```

onCreate() :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listItem = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, listItem);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    loadData();
}
```

Can someone help me how to fix this? I'm really newbie to try this volley, thank you.

Another java:
1. List. java

```
public class List {
//public int gambar;
public String nama;
public String suhu;
public String kelembapan;
public List (String nama, String suhu, String kelembapan) {

    this.nama = nama;
    this.suhu = suhu;
    this.kelembapan = kelembapan;
}
public String getNama(){
    return nama;
}
public String getSuhu(){
    return suhu;
}
public String getkelembapan(){
    return kelembapan;
}
```

}

2. CustomAdapter.java -> [screenshot code of CustomAdapter.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9XMX.png)

Comment: Where did you set your adapter? And where did you call `loadData()` method

Comment: I have adapter field, I set it in onResponse method, and I called LoadData() in onCreate () in MainActivity

Comment: recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view) define recylerview after listitem define

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MainActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Also set Layout Manager to your code before set Adater

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
```

Comment: What's your class name ?

Comment: MainActivity class

Comment: Still same. E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: See my updted answer you also need to set LayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

> In your onCreate method

```
        listitem = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(listitem);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        loadData();
```

> Now in LoadData() method replace this 2 line

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listItem);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> with below line

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It makes another error. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: for above error you have to declare and define list item before you add it in adapter.

Comment: Still error. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{papb.tugasweather/papb.tugasweather.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

Comment: have you define recylerview before? see my updated answer

Comment: Yes, wait I will send my recyclerview.java too

Comment: from volley response, if any item is not added in list item then it will show null pointer exception.Check first any item is added in list item. for that you can debug your code.

Comment: I want to ask, your volley response you got is correct?

Comment: I dont know, how to check it? I just want to retrieve data from OpenWeatherMap API